"Limit 1" SQL Query giving more than 1 result
What I'm trying to do is: for a given English ID, select all Spanish sentences that share that ID. But some of the results are returning multiple sentences with different ids, despite setting the English limit to 1. The English table doesn't repeat the ID, but the Spanish table does. Am I missing something super obvious here? Using MySQL/PopSQL.
SELECT spanish.sentence 
FROM spanish
WHERE spanish.id = (
    SELECT english.id 
    FROM english
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
);

Example data:
Spanish



ID
sentence




1
un chico


2
un jugador


2
una jugadora


3
una mujer



English



ID
sentence




1
a boy


2
a player


3
a woman



So the expected result from randomly choosing English "2" would be both "un jugador" and "una jugadora". But what I'm getting sometimes is "un chico" and "una jugadora" (2 different IDs) having set the ID limit to 1.

Some sample data in the form of DDL that reproduces the issue you describe would be helpful to add.

We can't really help without seeing an example of your data, but the limit on the inner query doesn't suggest that the outer query should also only produce one row, unless you can conclusively prove there is an exact one-to-one mapping of each spanish.id to each english.id. Additionally, your title is quite misleading. There is no indication the limit 1 isn't working as intended.

Edited data. The expected output can be more than one, as long as they all have the same ID. But I'm getting results with different IDs.

BTW, id is usually used for the primary key of a table, so it shouldn't have duplicates. Use english_id for the foreign key that relates to the english table.

The reason is that the subquery is re-evaluated for each row in the spanish table. Use JOIN instead of WHERE.

SELECT s.* FROM spanish AS s JOIN (SELECT id FROM english ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS e ON s.id = e.id;

Gotcha! That works, thanks. Why does the parenthetical expression in the WHERE clause not trigger first?

@Barmar post that as an answer?

@Barmar The question is re-opened now, that can be posted as an answer now.

Remove limit 1 from inner query and add in outer query.

Using limit inside your inner or nested query will only limit the result from your inner query and not the overall query. If I understand you correctly, you want to select all spanish sentences that correspond to each english sentence or id. If that is the case, using a left join would work to your purpose as you can use the query below to suit that purpose.
select english.id, english.sentence, spanish.sentence from english left join spanish on spanish.id = english.id

Now, if you would like to only query on a particular english id, you would have to use the where in your sql statement as below.
select english.id, english.sentence, spanish.sentence from english left join spanish on spanish.id = english.id
where english.id = 2

Using a limit 1 will only limit the number of rows to return from your sql query, in this case only 1 row.
